# Send a file with POST request using C# to Node.js server

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, windows-runtime

i've a node.js local server and i want to upload a file from WP to this server using a POST request. Node.js server can parse a multipart/form-data - read data from "files" and "fields" and save the file in a local folder using node-formidable library.

How i can send a request like this (using the web form) using C# for WinRT?:

> https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/04/27/Cattura.png

I try with this code:

```
        public async Task<string> SendWithMultiPartForm()
    {
        string servResp = "";
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary))
        {

            content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

            content.Add(new StreamContent(await fileToSend.OpenStreamForReadAsync()), "files", "files");

            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            handler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, SiteURI);
            request.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;
            request.Content = content;

            httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            servResp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        return servResp;
    }
```

but the result is:

> https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/04/27/Cattura2.png

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide content of images as text inline in the post.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful: http://goo.gl/7lVK0i